# conditions for existence of connected-étale exact sequence for finite flat group schemes over general bases

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a scheme and $G/X$ be a finite flat group scheme. I am interested in conditions on $X$ (e.g. $X$ the spectrum of a complete local Noetherian ring) such that there is a connected-étale exact sequence $0 \to G^0 \to G \to G^{\mathrm{\acute{e}t}} \to 0$ and conditions when this sequence splits.

Comment: Over an arbitrary base scheme local constancy of the order of the fibral etale part is clearly necessary, and it is also sufficient: see Lemma 4.8 (esp. its awesome proof) and the first paragraph of the proof of Proposition 4.9 in Chapter II of Messing's thesis (= Lecture Notes in Math 264, *The Crystals Associated to Barsotti-Tate Groups...*).

Comment: Beware that if $X$ is the spectrum of a complete local noetherian ring there is a common abuse of referring to the connected component of the identity section as $G^0$ even though the formation of such $G^0$ does *not* commute with non-local base change (e.g., passage to a generic fiber).  So it is important to clarify what the motivation is to determine if you want something as strong as the relative result in Messing's thesis or the weaker and easier-to-construct thing over some local rings. Splitting is a very restrictive condition (being over a perfect field is the only useful criterion).